# Latest libinput on ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, libinput

Coming mostly from Fedora and Archlinux I used to have the latest libinput available in a reasonable time. Currently, on ubuntu 18.04 I do not see how can I have the latest libinput e.g. 1.12 at the time of writing on my machine. Is there a ppa or has anyone tried to install it from source without messing up the whole system?

I do not mind to compile it but I am not well educated in testing it and making sure it is working in conjunction with other packages properly. Having ThinkPad TrackPoint I kinda feel having the latest libinput is crucial!

Comment: I was about to write an answer, but figured I don't know how to assemble a package correctly *(specifically, which packages your `libinput-git` would replace, there's more than one)*, and don't have Ubuntu handy to test *(I'm on Archlinux)*. Hopefully, you can build an answer upon my next comment.

Comment: More-or-less recent packages probably can be gotten [from here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libinput). Building from source is easy: `git clone https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput.git`, and then follow steps from the `build()` function [from here](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=libinput-git) *(correct libexecdir to /usr/lib/x86_something)*. And lastly, you need to assemble a package from it with `checkinstall -D make install` command.

Comment: To address the `making sure it is working in conjunction with other packages properly`: the `meson build` *(from the linked build() function)* will take care of dependencies *(and if not, it's a bug)*. You only need to take care of writing correct dependencies for package manager; checkinstall command will ask you about them *(I didn't look at man for checkinstall, but it's likely you can just write a config, and feed it to checkinstall)*. Main purpose is to not have same file `/foo` in two different packages, and hence of 2 different versions *(tho hopefully `apt` will throw an error then)*.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info in here. I never had experience with meson, and to be fair compilation has been fairly straightforward. I was just not sure if I should use the binaries since I didn't want to break anything, but since there is no other solution I will try and report in here about the outcome. thanks.

Comment: @Mohamad any news? Can you post were you able to update it or no?  If yes, steps would be great.

Comment: @VadimK Unfortunately no. I have no problem building the packages but for some reason I find the end result is not reliable. The precision of track point is not as good as default Fedora package.

Comment: I will leave it here. To let users find instructions on how to build libinput.  https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/building.html

Comment: Any updates on this? I have an annoying issue where the touchpad jumps a lot which is supposed to be fixed in new versions of libinput.

Comment: @VadimK I forgot to check the answers since my question is very old but I actually tried that link and it works very nicely and it has the solution for reinstalling the distro packages in case of a mess up. If you put that as an answer I will select it as the right answer, and others can at least have a solution (kinda).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully, someday someone will make a PPA with latest libinput. Until then, here are instructions on building such package yourself.

It's easy, instructions are mainly [taken from here](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/building.html). I assume you don't need to generate docs, so I don't install dependencies for them and disable them in `meson` call. It's also important for `--prefix` to be `usr` in meson-configuration line, so libraries are installed to standard locations.

### Step1: install build depenendencies

```bash
$ sudo apt install -y git ninja-build python3-pip
$ sudo apt build-dep libinput
$ sudo pip3 install meson
```

Note: although Meson is in Ubuntu repo, however in the snippet it is installed with pip. The reason is: due to Ubuntu mostly providing ancient software there's a possibility their Meson version will be too old to be able to build libinput. ATM Ubuntu 18.04 is known to have this problem, but I assume with time it may happen to other releases as well.

### Step2: clone and build libinput

```bash
$ git clone https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput
$ cd libinput
$ meson --prefix=/usr -Ddocumentation=false build/
$ ninja -C build/
```

### Step3: create libinput package and install

Though easiest way of installing built libinput is by running `ninja -C build install`, but I strongly discourage that unless you know what you're doing *(you will get untracked files all over your system that may get overwritten on system update, and depending on situation may even break libinput completely)*.

Instead, use [this script I've written](https://gist.github.com/Hi-Angel/45030ab89a2378b42511612cbe48d247) to assemble a package.

```bash
$ wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Hi-Angel/45030ab89a2378b42511612cbe48d247/raw/package-deb-libinput.sh
[…]
$ bash ./package-deb-libinput.sh  build/
[…]
dpkg-deb: building package 'libinput-git' in 'libinput_1.15.3-212-g60edbd2d.deb'.
```

You can see the name of the new package in the script output, so all that is left is to install it *(note: the `./` part in the path is needed for `apt` to correctly interpret argument as a local file)*:

```bash
$ sudo apt install -y ./build/libinput_1.15.3-212-g60edbd2d.deb
```

To make use of installed libinput you need to restart graphics session *(for example, reboot)*.

---

### Reverting to older libinput

May you wish to get back the distro-provided libinput, just install `libinput10` package *(it will replace `libinput-git`)*:

```bash
$ apt install -y libinput10
```

### Appendix

In case something happens to github gist, here's the current content of the script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Wrong number of parameters.
Usage: $(basename $0) build_dir"
    exit 1
fi

MESON_BUILD_ROOT=$(readlink -f $1)
PACKAGE_VERSION=$(grep -Po 'LIBINPUT_GIT_VERSION.*"\K.+(?=")' "$MESON_BUILD_ROOT"/libinput-git-version.h)
PKG_DIR="$MESON_BUILD_ROOT"/deb
mkdir -p $PKG_DIR/DEBIAN/
cat > $PKG_DIR/DEBIAN/control <<- END_OF_TEXT
PACKAGE: libinput-git
Version: $PACKAGE_VERSION
Architecture: amd64
Maintainer: Mystique Packager
Description: input device management and event handling library
Depends: libevdev2, libmtdev1, libudev1, libwacom2
Conflicts: libinput10, libinput-bin, libinput-dev, libinput-tools
Provides:  libinput10, libinput-bin, libinput-dev, libinput-tools
Homepage: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput
END_OF_TEXT

cd "$MESON_BUILD_ROOT"
DESTDIR=$PKG_DIR ninja install
fakeroot dpkg-deb --build $PKG_DIR/ libinput_$PACKAGE_VERSION.deb
```

Comment: I am trying to follow your instruction but when I do `sudo apt build-dep libinput` I got an error `You must put some 'deb-src' URIs in your sources.list`

Comment: Ok I realized I did not tick the "source code" in my updater. Now it works.