# cursor moves sideways on tap, libinput, Ubuntu 18.04, Lenovo y580

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, libinput

On my Lenovo y580, Ubuntu 18.04.1 with libinput 1.10.4.
When I tap to click or, take my finger from the touch, the pointer moves slightly sideways. Does someone know how to adjust this?

I've searched for an answer, but can't find any. Maybe only with the Synaptic driver, there are solutions, not with libinput.

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer      (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0    id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0    id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MOSART Semi. Trust Gaming Mouse           id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=19   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0    id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ MOSART Semi. Trust Gaming Mouse           id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lenovo EasyCamera: Lenovo EasyC           id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0    id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ MOSART Semi. Trust Gaming Mouse           id=21   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because touchpad is very sensitive. You're interested in [this commit](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/commit/734496d972152dc9998f884c840550dc34c7088a) in particular. It's part of libinput since 1.11.2, so you need to install at least 1.11.2 *(or better yet, install latest released, the 1.12 has a new feature "vertical/horizontal scroll locks")*.

That said, though this commit improves the situation, but it doesn't make it perfect, so if you still would be unsatisfied, [please file a bug](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/issues).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am new to linux and I couldn't install the new libinput 1.12, I think I'll wait for the official upgrade to the new version from Ubuntu.

Comment: @VNM you might be interested in the little discussion [under this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074244/latest-libinput-on-ubuntu). Unfortunately I can't write an answer there, as I don't currently have this distro *(I'm an Archlinux user)*, and can't do the necessary experimentation/testing.