# libinput - jumpy cursor issue

Tags: touchpad, synaptics, cursor, xps, libinput

I have a Dell XPS 15 9570 and with libinput, the cursor jumps if I move it too fast. The problem is solved by installing the synaptic driver, which is forced over the libinput driver.

```
$ sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

However, the problem with synaptics is that it doesn't detect my palm, so sometimes it jumps which is kind of bothering, because I am hovering over the touchpad when typing and my palm touches the touchpad.

Is there a way to fix the jumpy cursor in libinput or to have some kind of palm detection in synaptics?

Comment: Yes, you need to try [latest libinput](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074244/latest-libinput-on-ubuntu), and then if it doesn't work, [report a bug](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/reporting-bugs.html#reporting-bugs-touchpad). The developer of libinput is very active, so you may expect a reply within a working day-two.

Comment: Any updates? I have same issue on the XPS 13 7390.

Comment: @becko did you try latest libinput as per my prev. comment?