# Why libinput debounce state is DEBOUNCE_STATE_DISABLED?

Tags: mouse, libinput

I've installed libinput to enable debounce. I added settings to `/etc/libinput/local-overrides.quirks`. But it doesn't work.
I try to debug libinput with command `libinput debug-events --verbose` and it says:

```
event2  - debounce state: DEBOUNCE_STATE_DISABLED → DEBOUNCE_EVENT_OTHERBUTTON → DEBOUNCE_STATE_DISABLED
event2  - debounce state: DEBOUNCE_STATE_DISABLED → DEBOUNCE_EVENT_PRESS → DEBOUNCE_STATE_DISABLED
event2  - debounce state: DEBOUNCE_STATE_DISABLED → DEBOUNCE_EVENT_RELEASE → DEBOUNCE_STATE_DISABLED
```

So debounce doesn't work and I can't understand why.
My `local-overrides.quirks`:

```
[DEXIN Tt eSPORTS THERON]
MatchName=DEXIN Tt eSPORTS THERON
ModelBouncingKeys=1

[DEXIN Tt eSPORTS THERON Keyboard]
MatchName=DEXIN Tt eSPORTS THERON Keyboard
ModelBouncingKeys=1

[DEXIN Tt eSPORTS THERON Consumer Control]
MatchName=DEXIN Tt eSPORTS THERON Consumer Control
ModelBouncingKeys=1

[mouse]
MatchUdevType=mouse
ModelBouncingKeys=1

[THERON]
MatchName=*THERON*
ModelBouncingKeys=1

[DEXIN]
MatchName=*DEXIN*
ModelBouncingKeys=1
```

Comment: Here you meticulously disabled the debounce ☺ Libinput has it enabled by default, and what the `ModelBouncingKeys=1` quirk does is it says "bouncing keys for this model are, for whatever weird reason, the normal behavior" *(I admit, it may not be immediately clear from the naming, I had to double-check it locally too)*. IIRC one such example is the virtual mouse pointer in VMWare: it slightly delays the click, and so upon double-clicking clicks get sent very close in time. FTR: when debounce is enabled, instead of `DEBOUNCE_STATE_DISABLED` you'll see `DEBOUNCE_STATE_IS_UP`.

Comment: Oh, and btw, please note that quirks file is read when an application making use of libinput library is being started. It means that you can test the quirks with `libinput debug-events --verbose` immediately, because that utility is making use of the library and you just started it. But at the same time you'll see no actual changes in mouse behavior *(as opposed to entries in the `libinput-debug-events` log)* because your running Xorg/wayland-compositor are past the point they read the file, so you'll want to restart them.

Comment: @Hi-Angel thank you, it helped me. Mouse works much better. If you copy comment as answer, I accept it.

Comment: If you see some "bounces" are still getting through and you have any interest, you could experiment by changing the timeout when an event is considered a bounce. Sadly, it's not currently available as an option, so you'd have to [build libinput yourself](https://askubuntu.com/a/1305647/266507#latest-libinput-on-ubuntu) and modify the sources. The timeout is, I think *(I'm not completely sure, I just quickly grepped through sources)*, [is defined at this line](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/-/blob/4422e957474a3f5ce6b414bc7115a7e33585ec66/src/evdev-debounce.c#L127)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your text you meticulously disabled the debounce ☺ Libinput has it enabled by default, and what the `ModelBouncingKeys=1` quirk does is it says "bouncing keys for this model are, for whatever weird reason, the normal behavior" *(I admit, it may not be immediately clear from the naming, I had to double-check it locally too)*. IIRC one such example is the virtual mouse pointer in VMWare: it slightly delays the click, and so upon double-clicking clicks get sent very close in time.

When debounce is enabled, instead of `DEBOUNCE_STATE_DISABLED` you'll see `DEBOUNCE_STATE_IS_UP`