# Adjusting touchpad speed with synaptics but palm detection with libinput

Tags: 20.04, touchpad, synaptics, libinput

I am using a ThinkPad E595 with Ubuntu 20.04 and tried to alter the touchpad acceleration.

Since `xinput --list-props 13` didn't give me any options other than `libinput Accel Speed` I installed `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`. There I had the options `Device Accel Constant Deceleration` and `Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration` which did the trick and I got a nice touchpad feeling.

But this completely broke the palm detection. Uninstalling synaptics brought back the perfect palm detection from libinput.

Has anyone an idea how to get both, the nice touchpad experience and the palm detection?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

The options I have with libinput (xinput --list-props 13) to alter the touchpad behavior are:

```
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
Device Enabled (155):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (157): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
libinput Tapping Enabled (311): 1
libinput Tapping Enabled Default (312): 0
libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (313):    1
libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (314):    1
libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (315):   0
libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (316):   0
libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (317):  1, 0
libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (318):  1, 0
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (293):   0
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (294):   0
libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (319):    1
libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (320):    1
libinput Scroll Methods Available (295):    1, 1, 0
libinput Scroll Method Enabled (296):   1, 0, 0
libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (297):   1, 0, 0
libinput Click Methods Available (321): 1, 1
libinput Click Method Enabled (322):    1, 0
libinput Click Method Enabled Default (323):    1, 0
libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (300):    0
libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (301):    0
libinput Accel Speed (302): 0.400000
libinput Accel Speed Default (303): 0.000000
libinput Left Handed Enabled (307): 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (308): 0
libinput Send Events Modes Available (278): 1, 1
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (279):    0, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (280):    0, 0
Device Node (281):  "/dev/input/event6"
Device Product ID (282):    2, 7
libinput Drag Lock Buttons (309):   <no items>
libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (310):   1`
```

Comment: You probably swapped what you wanted to do in the title? As in, you probably wanted to adjust touchpad speed with libinput, not synaptics. Either way, you didn't mention what's wrong with libinput options. Regarding acceleration, libinput has two options "speed" and "acceleration profile" *(which can be`adaptive` and `flat`)* . Are these two not sufficient? Regarding synaptics, well, apparently it has no palm-detection feature. I don't think there's anything you can do, synaptics is a long deprecated and unmaintained project.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and sorry for being confusing. To be honest I am a bit confused. 

For the touchpad I only have the option "speed" (see edit). And altering this gives me either for short distances or long distances an unsatisfying behavior.

But for the trackpoint I have the option "Accel Profiles Available", "Accel Profile Enabled" and "Accel Profile Enabled Default". I couldn't manage to find a way to change this option. Do you maybe know how? "wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/configuration.html" and "www.mankier.com/4/libinput" didn't really help me.

Comment: Hmm, `man 4 libinput` says, not all devices can have AccelProfile. But it doesn't say what determines that. It seems [profiles are implemented inside libinput, assigned by `tp_init_accel`](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/-/blob/c5d6b3f6e8fdbb9427c69a3bcb29fce9c0a5e6e4/src/evdev-mt-touchpad.c#L2980), so missing profiles would be a question to it. I'd recommend testing latest libinput, then if it still lacks `Accel Profile`, [report a bug upstream](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/reporting_bugs.html#reporting_bugs_touchpad).

Comment: Yeah, and changing a profile if these options were available, would be something like: `xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "libinput Accel Profile Enabled" 1, 0`. Oh, btw, please see also if executing `libinput debug-events --verbose` will give any hints on what could be the problem with touchpad.

Comment: Thanks, changing the profile for my trackpoint worked. I had to write the name of the device like you did instead of just the number like I did. The `libinput debug-events --verbose` didn't give me anything interesting.

Comment: Thanks also for your hint with to install the newest version of libinput. I found your instruction [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074244/latest-libinput-on-ubuntu). But since I never build my own packages I will try it when I have some spare time.

Comment: Btw, for trackpoints acceleration there were a couple of interesting technical posts by the libinput creator and maintainer Peter Hutterer. Here's the [first one](https://who-t.blogspot.com/2018/06/observations-on-trackpoint-input-data.html), just in case you are into that kind of articles.