# libwacom2 dependency

Tags: dependencies

I'm trying to update libinput by building the package from github, as I found that libinput 1.22 solves my ThinkPad trackpoint drift, but at the end, when I try to install it, it says:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libinput-git : Depends: libwacom2 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
What can I do? I followed this to build it:
[Latest libinput on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074244/latest-libinput-on-ubuntu)
I'm on 22.10.

Comment: I said that it fixed the problem because I switched briefly to Arch and with 1.22 I didn't have any drift, would you say I could still have it with 1.22 on ubuntu?

Comment: Ok so I tested and while drifting happened less frequently than it does on 22.10 with libinput 1.21, it seems like it is still there sometimes, I don’t know why on arch it was completely gone.